# Prevent automatic SharePoint Log in with cookies from another SharePoint account

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

When you frequently log in to a SharePoint website Y on one machine, the browser remembers you with cookies. Then, if you try to go to a different SharePoint website X (totally unrelated site), your browser tries to log you in with the original credentials for website X. Of course, this fails and you get a log in error.

My question is, is there someway to make it so your SharePoint website Y does not accept any cookies in this way? So that every time you go to it, it ignores any cookies someone may have on their machine and give a blank log in screen.

I am looking for a way to do this that does not involve changing individual users browser settings, since many people from around the country will be logging in and naturally, I cannot be at their computer to set up their browser to ignore cookies.

I am working with Office 365, and making a website inside of that.

Thank You if you have a solution/help with this.

Comment: you have control over website X & Y ?

Comment: @Nikhil I only have control over website X. Website Y would be some other website unrelated to mine, but it is causing users of my site trouble.

Comment: u can clear all the cookies when you login to site X but that will impact site Y . Can you check the session of the users when they login to your site and redirect to a login screen . hmm but not sure.

Comment: @Nikhil hmm yeah, if you could check the session of the user when they first go to my site Y, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this should be happening is if one website was a sub-domain of another.  If so, because of domain cookie sharing, the cookie would be sent to the other website.

I've highlighted other concerns when using multiple SharePoint farms where one is a subdomain of another on my blog:  http://steve.thelineberrys.com/sharepoint-dns-name-considerations-when-using-anonymous-access-2/

The best thing to do is to change the dns of your SharePoint site so one is not a sub-domain of the other.

Answer (score 0):

@user244034 I am not sure I understand this completely.

- Is website Y a sub-domain of website X? For ex. X = somewebsite.com, and Y = otherwebsite.somewebsite.com
- Are both websites bound to the same SSO provider? If so, this may help, but it is a little old: http://www.shailensukul.com/2010/05/adfs-2-sharepoint-2010-signout.html

HTH